# 9-pin mini-DIN - zero resistance between some pins

Tags: resistance, controller, music

There's a volume knob connected to a speaker system with 9-pin mini-DIN. The volume knob contains potentiometer to control volume and is also in charge of turning the system on and off (by turning the knob counter-clockwise up to the end). Some time ago I suddenly wasn't able to turn the system on and now I decided to have a look at what's going on.

I discovered that pins 4, 5, 6, 8 and the round metal pin wrapper (socket, collar?) have no resistance between each other. Is it wrong or is it normal or it depends? I suspect this of the fact that the system couldn't be turned on any more.

What do you think?

[image: DIN <> PCB]
[image: PCB]

Comment: I think, you should look up the schematic for your device.

Comment: Connecting several pins and the shield to ground would be normal practice. Exactly which pins? For that, as Nick says, you need the schematic.

Comment: I've updated the question with photos of DIN, PCB and their interconnections. That would be a nice suprise if such a schematic was available - it's Creative GigaWorks T3‎ - I've googled it but to no avail.

Comment: @PetaSittek If you look at the other side of the PCB, you might see that several pins (e.g. 4,5,6,8 and the casing) are connected together there. That would make it deliberate. However, first you should check that the circuit is getting the correct voltage.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your photo, it seems like pins 1,2,3,7 and 9 are connected to different points at the contact on the board. As others have said, this does not imply that the other pins are connected togheter, but it would be quite a surprise if the unused pins are short circuited by accident. 
So to answer your question:

1) It is probably correct that you find a 0-ohm resistance between those pins

2) It is therefore probably another reason that the system does not work.

To give a definite answer, a diagram is needed, although it may be possible to imply something from a picture of the other side of the PCB.

Looking a bit closer at your original photo - it is stated that the orange, yellow, gray, white and black leads are all connected to "DIN04568" which looks suspiciously much like pins 4,5,6 and 8. (0 probably being the shielding) so I would say that they really look to be connected by design.

Comment: Thank You, I've uploaded the photo of the other side of PCB. Can You deduce something from it?

Comment: Nope, sorry,,,,

Answer (score 2):

The audio jacks on there likely have built in switches, allowing audio to be diverted. The larger one looks like it probably has an extra switch as well. When there is no plug, well, plugged in, the switches close, rerouting audio, which would show up as a short.

You could disconnect the wire from it's connector and then test for continuity, and you will see that none of the pins are internally connected in the cable or housing.

**Also, since this is an audio device**, the grounds for multiple audio channels could be broken out. Instead of a single ground, they could have 1 ground per audio channel. Left Output, Ground, Right Output, Ground, Left Input, Ground, etc. This is fairly common. ***It is possible that something broke, but it could be by design***.

General Idea of the jacks:

[image]
[image]

You can also test the pot to make sure the power switch built into it is still working. One of the pins will be OPEN to the rest when it is clicked off, and have either a short or some resistance when clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the white connector and see if those pins are still shorted at the DIN-9
end.  If they are I bet you have a failed cable (look for signs of a point that has been pinched or crushed.

If they are all open from each other, then check the continuity from the white plug end to the DIN-9. They should all be connected.

If that is also OK, then meter across adjacent pins at the PCB end. See if the same pins are shorted together. (it may be OK).

Have you verified that the power supply is OK and not broken at that end. If it uses a wall-wart that is a much more likely source of failure...

Comment: Good point. Always make it as simple as possible when looking for faults.